# How can I view photospheres on a PC?

Tags: google-photos

I shot a photosphere on my phone, and it was uploaded automatically to http://photos.google.com.  However, I can't seem to view it as a photosphere.  How can I view it on my computer?

Comment: Unless things have changed, the only way was to view them on Google+ (Google's social network - very crafty!). However, there is an API available if you want to display them on your own website. (Maybe there's now some apps - using the API - that allow you to do this?)

Comment: I tried going into Google+ and viewing my photos there, but it just took me to http://photos.google.com.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue before when shooting panorama pictures. The thing is that a panorama picture has metadata in it that tells your computer (of Google Photos for that matter) that it is indeed a panorama picture.

Google has a [tool](https://photo-sphere.appspot.com/) for adding that metadata in a picture.